# Laravel authentication issues getUser failing, check working

Tags: php, session, laravel, laravel-4

I have one route to login and return the logged in user which successfully returns the user model

```
return Auth::getUser();
```

I have another route that simple returns the logged in user, but it returns `null`

```
Route::get('authUser', function () {
    return Auth::getUser();
});
```

Finally, I have a third route that checks if the user is logged in, which returns `true`

```
return Auth::check();
```

How could `Auth::getUser()` return `null`, but `Auth::check()` return `true`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both `Auth::getUser()` and `Auth::user()` exist but there is a very important difference between them. `Auth::getUser()` will only return a **cached** user. That means if the user is authenticated in the session it will still return null. Only if the user has been loaded into the cache (e.g. by calling `Auth::user()`) you'll get the user model returned.

That means you should use `Auth::user()` in your code.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I couldn't find any docs on getUser (last time I make an assumption based on IDE intellisense)

Comment: I regret that I did not find this answer 5 hours ago.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know

```
Auth::getUser()
```

But I think you meant:

```
Auth::user()
```

Check it out...